# JSONP requests and responses. with Javascript

Tags: javascript, request, jsonp

A web service has 3 parameters;

callback,
x,
y

how do I send these to the webservice?

I'm seeing a lot of complex examples, and a lot of stuff in jquery. Could someone give me an example of how that request would look like.

Answer (score 0):

A JSONP request will be packaged into a script tag request that will be essentially equivalent to this:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain.com/yourscript?callback=foo&x=3&y=29"></script>
```

The parameters to the JSONP call are passed as URL query parameters.

The request will return a piece of javascript that calls the callback name and passes it the return results of the JSONP call.

This is all a giant hack to work-around the [same-origin security restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) in browsers and works only with cooperating web sites that specifically support access via JSONP.  More modern browsers support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to allow ajax calls to other origins (if the origin permits it).